# fastest way to find geo points within a range in mysql

Tags: mysql, geolocation, range, latitude-longitude

I would like to query for all possible **streetnames within a radius of 500 meters** of a given point. 
Multiple posts are reffering to the google store locator example using the **Haversine formula** or some version of it.
But I also came across some posts that have a **much more simplified solution**.

They just treat the points as x,y coordinates by **adding to the lat and long** variables as seen below.

I was wandering if this would be the **fastest way to query mysql** without getting really complicated and still get a good result. I don't have a lot of data yet, so I want to know if I am on the right track.
Are there any **disadvantages or inaccuracy's** by using this method?

What I don't get is how this can be a radius like range, it looks more like a one directional 
query?

```
Distance = 0.1; // Range in degrees (0.1 degrees is close to 11km)
LatN = lat + Distance;
LatS = lat - Distance;
LonE = lon + Distance;
LonW = lon - Distance;

...Query DB with something like the following:
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE 
(store_lat BETWEEN LatN AND LatS) AND
(store_lon BETWEEN LonE AND LonW)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask this question on [the GIS site](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions).  I've used [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/31628) myself for similar problems.  I can see how your proposed solution might be faster, but note your four points are describing a square not a circle so it would not be considered a "radius".

Comment: I know what to do now, first filter with the coords from above and put the Haversine formula in the where clause. I just have to figure out if I have the correct formula for finding the coords for the rectangle(upleft and downright). I saw calculations in other posts and the above just adds/substracts a radius and that's possibly less accurate?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ElasticSearch for that, MySQL will be always slower than ES.